# How do I fix AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'?

Tags: python

This is my code `z = (priv.to_string().encode('hex'))`
and I got this error:

```
"AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'"
```

looks like I missed something to show "encode" after the code:

`z = (priv.to_string().`

Comment: What is `priv`'s type?
Try `str(priv)` rather than `priv.to_string()`

Comment: it is a string, i put hex() after "z = (priv.to_string(). and after .encode this is my code now and it's fine "z = (priv.to_string().hex().encode(hex()) but i have syntax error in my next code print, here is my next code "print("private key = "+z+" " + "address = 0x"+address)"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two problems here:

- you're using `priv.to_string()` (which isn't a built-in method) instead of `str(priv)`
- `'hex'` has been removed as an encoding in Python 3, so with `str(priv).encode('hex')` you'll get the following error: `LookupError: 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode()to handle arbitrary codecs`

However, since Python 3.5, you can simply do:

```
priv.hex()
```

with `priv` being a byte string.

Example:

```
priv = b'test'
print(priv.hex())
```

Output:

```
74657374
```

Comment: I modified my code: "z = str(priv.to_string().hex().encode())" and it works! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

on Python3 systems older than version 3.5, you can `from binascii import hexlify` and use `hexlify(priv.to_string())`